# Is this just a direct consequence of the Maximum-Modulus Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

Let $D$ be a bounded region and $f$ is an analytic function on $D$. Show that if there is a constant $c ≥ 0$ such that $|f(z)| = c$ for all $z$ in the boundary of $D$ then either $f$ is a constant function or $f$ has a zero in $D$.

Is this just a direct consequence of the Maximum-Modulus Theorem?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "direct". For a sufficiently narrow definition, it's an indirect consequence.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please? If it's not, then how would I go about showing it?

Comment: It is a consequence of the maximum modulus theorem. The question is whether you call it direct or not. To show it, make a case distinction between $c = 0$ and $c > 0$. For $c = 0$, it is a direct consequence of the maximum modulus theorem that $f \equiv 0$. For $c > 0$, suppose $f$ has no zero in $D$. Then apply the maximum modulus theorem to something in order to deduce that $f$ is constant.

Comment: $f$ is only defined in $D$, so what does $f$ on the boundary mean?

Comment: @zhw. $f$ is defined on the boundary of D to be a constant function s.t. $f$ is continuous on the closure of D. The last part was forgotten to be mentioned by the author.